# How to limit voltage readings to within a range, that go into a log file?

Tags: python, logging, range

I have a device that takes voltage readings that go into a Python 2.7 program. The program works fine but I would like for voltages that are too low to not go into the log file. Voltage readings run from 0.1 to 2.5 volts and I'm only interested in voltage readings above 1.1 volts. Here is my program:

```
 import time, sys, math
 import adc
 from time import time, sleep
 import logging
 ADS1015 = 0x01
 adc=ADS1x15(ic=ADS1015)
 with open('logfile.txt', 'a') as f:
     while True:
        volts = adc.readADC01(4096, 8)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        print >> f, time(), '{:.0f}'.format(volts)
        sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put an `if` statement in there after `while True` once you've taken the reading, saying `if volts < 1.1`, `sleep(1)`, then `continue` the loop.

Comment: That's all I needed, an if statement.

Comment: @Rico, actually there are several ways you can do this, but I suggested the way I did because it can be inserted. I might rewrite it and say, `if volts > 1.1`, then `flush stdout` and `print`, so you only need one `sleep` statement, and no `continue`. It's easier to read and is less hacked together.